# Validating character or space through masked text box in vb6

Tags: vb6

I was using masked text box in my project.I have come across a situation which need the masked text box to accept only an alphabet or an space as a last character of my string.I know an option in masked text box the accept only number or space.Is there any possibilities to get an alphabet or space likewise?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There are a lot of masked edit controls out there, which one are you using?

Comment: I have been using maskEDBox control.It looks like '##|' in standard control tab.Pls let me know for further clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the & (ampersand)?